# Display selected option in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, edit

I want to display the already selected option when editing my data, but it doesn't show the correct chosen option. how do i show the correct option?

My code:

```
<div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="Jurusan" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Jurusan</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <select class="form-control" id="jurusan" name="jurusan">
                              <option value="" >Pilih</option>
                                <?php foreach($jurusan as $row):?>
                                <option <?php if($row->id_jurusan == $row->id_jurusan){ echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?> value="<?php echo $row->id_jurusan; ?>"><?php echo $row->nama_jurusan;?> </option>
                                <?php endforeach;?>
                            </select>
                            <small class="text-danger">
                                <?php echo form_error('jurusan') ?>
                            </small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: There is probably a misconception here: `if($row->id_jurusan == $row->id_jurusan)` is always true, you are comparing the same thing.

Comment: @daniel i'm aware of that, it's just this is the only code that i could find that seem to be working for displaying the selected option, but like i said it doesn't show the correct selected option

Comment: how do you know what needs to be selected? you must compare `if($row->id_jurusan == $selected_id)` as an example.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like i found the answer, the correct code should be this

```
<option <?php if($row->id_jurusan == $data_form->id_jurusan){ echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?> value="<?php echo $row->id_jurusan; ?>"><?php echo $row->nama_jurusan;?> </option>
```

$data_form is from my controller, to get the primary key

```
$data["data_form"] = $form->getById($id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just you this

```
<option <?php if($row->id_jurusan == $data_form->id_jurusan){ echo 'selected'; } ?> value="<?php echo $row->id_jurusan; ?>"><?php echo $row->nama_jurusan;?> </option>
```

You can use this code.